# Are there associated costs with SageMaker Debugger?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker-debugger

Are there associated costs with SageMaker Debugger? Everywhere I look it says that there are no additional costs, but this has me curious as to what underlying resources the service uses.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [SageMaker pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/), there's no additional cost when you use built-in rules for debugging. But if you use custom rules then you'll need to specify an instance size and there will be a cost associated to that instance for the duration of the training job.

Also this documentation details the architecture, and explains that debugging for built-in rules happens in processing containers managed by Debugger.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/debugger-how-it-works.html